# Modified Sliding window

Tags: java

Recently I was being asked a problem in an interview, which is modified version of continuous sum of k size in array.
So the problem goes like this:
Give maximum continuous sum of k elements in array a. We can choose only k element either from start or end or k-1 element from start and 1 element from end or k-2 element from start and 2 element from end 2 element from start and k-2 element from end, etc.
Example:

```
[5,-2,3,1,2]
k=3

o/p:8

all possible combinations:[5,-2,3],[3,1,2][5,2,1],[-2,5,2]
max sum combinations: [5,2,1], etc
```

Can anyone explains logic in java.

Comment: I'm not following the explanation. Can you show how you got to the possible combinations step by step?

Comment: @Branson Smith: I think it's a sliding window that can wrap around the end of the array to the beginning.  Which would make the OP's example answer 8, not 6.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes the output is 8, and exactly its sliding window that wrap around. Can I have some clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the result from one of my test runs.

```
Input array   [5, -2, 3, 1, 2]
Window length 3
Current window  [5, -2, 3]
Sum of current window 6
Current window  [-2, 3, 1]
Sum of current window 2
Current window  [3, 1, 2]
Sum of current window 6
Current window  [1, 2, 5]
Sum of current window 8
Current window  [2, 5, -2]
Sum of current window 5
Maximum sum   8
```

With a wrap-around sliding window, there are exactly as many windows as there are values in the input array.  The window length doesn't matter, as long as it is less than the length of the array.

The "trick" is to make sure the array subscript is always less than the length of the array.  So, we use the remainder (`%`) operator to make sure the array index is always between 0 and array.length - 1;

Here's the complete runnable code. Try it with different arrays and different window lengths.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WrapAroundSlidingWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WrapAroundSlidingWindow wasw = new WrapAroundSlidingWindow();
        
        int[] array = { 5, -2, 3, 1, 2 };
        int k = 3;
        System.out.println("Input array   " + Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("Window length " + k);
        System.out.println("Maximum sum   " + wasw.calculateMaximumSum(array, k));
    }
    
    public int calculateMaximumSum(int[] array, int windowLength) {
        int maximumSum = calculateSum(array, 0, windowLength);
        System.out.println("Sum of current window " + maximumSum);
        
        for (int index = 1; index < array.length; index++) {
            int sum = calculateSum(array, index, windowLength);
            System.out.println("Sum of current window " + sum);
            maximumSum = Math.max(maximumSum, sum);
        }
        
        return maximumSum;
    }
    
    private int calculateSum(int[] array, int startIndex, int windowLength) {
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.print("Current window  [");
        
        for (int index = 0; index < windowLength; index++) {
            int jndex = (startIndex + index) % array.length;
            System.out.print(array[jndex]);
            if (index < windowLength - 1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            sum += array[jndex];
        }
        System.out.println("]");
        
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks @gilbert, also one more restriction in this question is we are supposed to take on either left most and right most. so window [-2, 3, 1] is not valid. window size 3 mean first 2 last 1 or first 1, last 2 or first 3 or last 3.